# Merge multiple m4a files

Tags: software-recommendation, music, m4a

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have several folders with music files that I want to join. So it would be good if there is a batch solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

`brew install ffmpeg sox`

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%m4a}wav"; done
sox *.wav combined.wav
ffmpeg -i combined.wav -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ab 192k combined.m4a
rm *.wav
```

Comment: Decompressing to wav, then recompressing may generate significant compression artifacts...

Comment: @AdamDavis Yeah, there are utilities to merge MP3 files without re-encoding (like mp3cat), but I didn't find anything for AAC.

Comment: Fission can merge MP3 and AAC without re-encoding. That is one of its great strengths.

Comment: I use the hombrew version of ffmpeg on macOS and it doesn't have libfaac. But "-acodec aac" works with their version. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I use Rogue Ameoba's excellent [Fission](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/fission/) to do this.

> Join Files. Drag and drop one file into another to instantly join them
>   together.

Not quite a batch process if you've got *lots* of files to join, but dragging and dropping audio files to concatenate into its window is straightforward. Fission does have a free trial but won't allow you to save anything without degrading the audio.

[image]

Are these files you want to join part of the same audio stream that have been split up? Be aware that if you're joining compressed audio, the transitions between one track and another at the point of the join may not be seamless, as the compression process removes part of the audio which may be audible when joined back together (if they're lossless, then there should be no problem).

Alternatively, if you want something free, I beleive [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/) will also do this for you.

Comment: I second this recommendation. Audacity is free and powerful, with a huge list of features, but awkward to use for many of them. Fission is streamlined and very capable for certain functions, and easy to use. Check the feature list

Comment: Unfortunately Fission requires only one file that can be dropped at a time and you can't multi select a bunch of files and drop to add all of them to the existing track.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Garageband** too.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cheap shot, but [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to simply copy/paste your tracks into one file. So, no batch solution like you were looking for, but easy copy/paste.

You'll need to download and install the [FFmpeg Import/Export Library](http://manual.audacityteam.org/help/manual/man/faq_installation_and_plug_ins.html#ffdown) though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Join Together from Doug's Scripts works very well if you've already imported the files into itunes. http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/jointogether.php  I've used this to convert audio books ripped from CD's to chaptered m4b but works with m4a as well